# T-SQL cursor encoding

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with column with cyrillic text. I want to iterate the table and proccess the rows one by one.

```
DECLARE @safeSize VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @safeId   INT 


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
  select coalesce(s.id,0), coalesce(s.size,'-')
    from old_nom_trezor s
    order by s.id

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @safeId, @safeSize

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       print @safeSize -- prints ???
       print @safeId   -- prints ???

       --Insert statement with the vars. Also inserts ?

       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @safeId, @safeSize
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

The problem is that the cyrillic symbols are printed as `?` and also if I insert them in other table the result is `?`. Simple select in the Management studio displays the right symbols. How can I fetch the cyrillic symbols in cyrillic?

Comment: What is the collation of your database? What if you change it to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS?

Comment: I think you need NVARCHAR(50) for your @safeSize variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys. I will try both tomorrow.

Comment: @DMason your solution worked, thanks. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: why on earth are you using a cursor for this? Cursors are a technique of last resort and should be avoided. The code is much simpler using a set-based approach as well. Please read: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Cursors_and_How_to_Avoid_Them

Comment: @HLGEM I have to migrate single legacy table to multiple tables. There are data type transformations, wiring FKs, some data is not valid ans so on...

Comment: I would still do all that in set based code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyrillic text consists of unicode characters, which can't be stored in a VARCHAR datatype.

Change this `DECLARE @safeSize VARCHAR(50)`
to this `DECLARE @safeSize NVARCHAR(50)`